# What came before Judaism?

Tags: messengers

Judaism came around about 1800BC
From the study of historic paintings, carvings, sculptures etc it seems that humanity only tapped into monotheism recently as the historic art based upon religion showed little to no signs of monotheism.
Also before Judaism there were long periods of time where a vast amount of the population would worship idols, numerous Gods or no Gods at all because of little understanding of monotheism. There were long periods of time without monotheism it seems and those living in areas where monotheism was not practised may have been doomed from birth. Even if there were messengers somewhere it seems that they came after long periods of time and only impacted small populations.
What came before Judaism? Were there any messengers or prophets  who taught monotheism? How long were the periods?

Comment: The view of Islam is that Allah taught us monotheism (Islam) since Adam. And this should be covered several times on our site.

Comment: But during history there were very few prophets there wouldn’t have been enough. There would have been long gaps and periods of times without prophets or at least a large amount of the population at the time wouldn’t have been aware of the prophet/messenger due to communication or the message wasn’t widespread e.g Noah

Comment: And? Your comment doesn't look on-topic to me unless you may elaborate and show the relevance.

Comment: Why isn’t it on-topic? It is a crucial topic about Islam and monotheism in Islam and whether God is Just by sending messengers or not sending them.

Comment: Your question topic is about Judaism. You should elaborate in this context.

Comment: It isn’t about Judaism it is about what came before Judaism because that is seemingly the last of the well documented monotheistic religions. Read please.

Comment: I've read and gave you the hint that this is obviously not the view of Islam Judaism is a religion created by people who were following the Islam as revealed to the(ir) prophets since Adam. And your question is already covered search for an existing answer on the site. Refer to it if you feel like missing something.

Comment: I tried searching and couldn’t find it which is why I asked. Also the question isn’t based about Judaism it is about what came before it. This then goes to what we believe in ISLAM about how many prophets and messengers came before this

Answer (score -1):

Well, historically, we can't get much information from before 3000 BC. But I can assure you, Prophet Adam, Nuh, Abraham, Yaqub, etc. were all preaching monotheism.

[EDIT BELOW]

Allah, The Most Just, will not doom a person if he/she was ignorant of the truth.  If what you say is true, such will be the case with such nations. Here's my counterargument.

Allah says in Surah Nahl(16:36): We raised a Messenger in every community (to tell them): "Serve Allah and shun the Evil One." Thereafter Allah guided some of them while others were overtaken by error. Go about the earth, then, and observe what was the end of those who rejected the Messengers, calling them liars. [END OF AYAH] Indeed, if history did not record something, it does not mean it didn't happen.

Allah also says in Surah Ghafir(40:78): And We have already sent messengers before you. Among them are those [whose stories] We have related to you, and among them are those [whose stories] We have not related to you. And it was not for any messenger to bring a sign [or verse] except by permission of Allah . So when the command of Allah comes, it will be concluded in truth, and the falsifiers will thereupon lose [all]. [END OF AYAH] I mentioned this Ayah because the number of total Prophets sent is unknown. Yes, you find Hadith about the total Prophets being 124,000 and 315 were messengers, BUT THESE HADITH ARE VERY VERY DA'EEF. So the Ayah in Surah Ghafir is enough to know that there are more Prophets in history than we know.

Remember, Allah will keep his religion alive till the Day of Judgement.

Comment: But during history there were very few prophets there wouldn’t have been enough. There would have been long gaps and periods of times without prophets or at least a large amount of the population at the time wouldn’t have been aware of the prophet/messenger due to communication or the message wasn’t widespread e.g Noah

Comment: Check out the edit.